Blank output in PeopleSoft Query Expression
I am trying to provide the variance between two fields as its own column. I have a simple expression: B.CHNG_NBR_VALUE - D.MERCHANDISE_AMT and added it as a field. It works when both B. and D. fields have values.
However, if the value in B. is 0, then the output in this new column is blank.
What can I add to the expression to make the output a negative of D. if B. is 0 (blank)?
I tried nesting in a conditional CASE WHEN statement to provide '-' || D.MERCHANDISE_AMT if B.CHNG_NBR_VALUE = ' '
But, that did not work.

Try the following:
NVL(B.CHNG_NBR_VALUE, 0) - NVL(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT, 0)

B.CHNG_NBR_VALUE and D.MERCHANDISE_AMT may possibly return null so the statement above will make sure that you do not subtract using null as a value but 0 instead.

Have you checked whether your column is defined as a signed or unsigned number? An incorrect field type might be causing the issue.
In PeopleSoft, a NULL value is treated as 0 for numeric columns, and vice versa.
Therefore, in my opinion, the issue might not be related to 0.
